# If B is derived from A by elementary transformations, can i conclusion inverter A=inverter B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Exercise E: Consider the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3\\3&2&-1\\-2&-1&2 \end{bmatrix}$$E1. Compute $\det(A)$.
> E2. Find $A^{-1}$.

In question E2 if $B$ is derived from $A$ by elementary transformations, can I conclusion  inverter $A = \text{inverter}B$?

Comment: The elementary operation should be $[A|I]\sim \cdots \sim [I|A^{-1}]$ by Gauss-Jordan elimination (if $\det(A)\not=0)$, of course).

Comment: @user1027216 If i tranform $A$ to Identity matrix, can i conclusion $A^{-1}=I$?

Comment: No. That is the idea of an algorithm, you can read all the details in every textbooks of linear algebra or for example here: https://online.stat.psu.edu/statprogram/reviews/matrix-algebra/gauss-jordan-elimination

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is no. If matrix $B$ is derived by elementary transformations from matrix $A$, you **can't** conclude that $A^{-1}=B^{-1}$.

To compute the invertible matrix of $A$, where $det(A) \neq 0$, you can use the **Gauss-Jordan elimination**:
$$(A,I) \sim \cdots \sim (I,A^{-1}).$$
Hope that helps!